# Resize CGImageRef without anti-liasing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, scaling, nsimage, cgimageref

I am trying to resize a 10x10 pixel CGImageRef, captured like this:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(screenShot, CGRectMake(mouseLoc.x-5, screen_height-mouseLoc.y-5, 10, 10));

CGContextRef mainViewContentContext = CGBitmapContextCreate (NULL, maskImage.size.width, maskImage.size.height, 8, maskImage.size.height*4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

CGContextDrawImage(mainViewContentContext, NSMakeRect(0,0, maskImage.size.width, maskImage.size.height), imageRef);
```

Then I need to make a 250x250 pixel image like this [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlLJ2.png), but the upscaled image looks like there is anti aliasing on it (looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG2Wg.png))

Comment: Interesting question. Most of the time people are asking for the reverse.

Comment: Just for people's reference and ease of Googling, what's happening here is called **interpolation**, not antialiasing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try `CGContextSetInterpolationQuality`:

```
// disable interpolation like this:
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(mainViewContentContext, kCGInterpolationNone);
// now draw
```

Comment: same thing :( I'm not getting perfect pixels

Comment: @Marek i misread your question. the example i made *enforces* HQ interpolation - updating...